# Ruby Returning unexpected nil

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a RSpec problem. According to that problem I have written a solution in ruby. But when running with RSpec Where I expect to get a value, I am getting `nil` here is the RSpec

```
require 'timer'

describe "Timer" do
  before(:each) do
    @timer = Timer.new
  end

  it "should initialize to 0 seconds" do
    expect(@timer.seconds).to eq(0)
  end

  describe 'time_string' do
    it "should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00" do
      @timer.seconds = 0
      expect(@timer.time_string).to eq("00:00:00")
    end

    it "should display 12 seconds as 00:00:12" do
      @timer.seconds = 12
      expect(@timer.time_string).to eq("00:00:12")
    end

    it "should display 66 seconds as 00:01:06" do
      @timer.seconds = 66
      expect(@timer.time_string).to eq("00:01:06")
    end

    it "should display 4000 seconds as 01:06:40" do
      @timer.seconds = 4000
      expect(@timer.time_string).to eq("01:06:40")
    end
  end
```

Here's the solution I wrote:

```
class Timer
     attr_accessor :seconds, :time_string


    def seconds=(num)
     @seconds=num
   end #seconds


     def time_string
       s=@seconds%60
       m=@seconds/60
       h=m/60
       m=m%60
       @time_string="%02d:%02d:%02d" %[h,m,s]
     end #time_string
end #class
```

Error I am getting

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@timer.seconds).to eq(0)

       expected: 0
            got: nil
```

Comment: Which example fails? Could you show the failure message?

Comment: ` Failure/Error: expect(@timer.seconds).to eq(0)
     
       expected: 0
            got: nil`

Comment: BTW, your `seconds=` method is redundant – `attr_accessor :seconds` implements that method for you. On the other hand, you can remove `attr_accessor :time_string` because you probably don't want to set `@time_string` from the outside. That said, `@time_string=` is superfluous (the instance variable is never used), you can just return the string. And you might want to take a look at [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod), e.g. `h, m = m.divmod(60)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you initialize `Timer.new` without any arguments. Thus, the `seconds` is `nil`

You need either:

```
before(:each) do
  @timer = Timer.new
  @timer.seconds = 0
end
```

Or implement an initializer:

```
class Timer
  attr_accessor :seconds, :time_string

  def initialize
    @seconds = 0
  end
  ...
```